# JSNI Hello World is not working

Tags: javascript, gwt, jsni

I have done a simple *Hello World* GWT example using JSNI. It does nothing but display a message.

This is the code in an EntryPoint class:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  alert("Hello World!");
 }
 native void alert(String msg) /*-{
  $wnd.alert(msg);
 }-*/;
}
```

I see this Exception:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the sample GWT project and copied your code into the entry point and it worked fine. I think you have a deeper set up problem. I would look over your *.gwt.xml file and make sure it isn't malformed and check your GWT library references etc. Also open up the Run Configration and make sure it is a Web Application.

```
    /**
 * Entry point classes define <code>onModuleLoad()</code>.
 */
public class So implements EntryPoint {


    native void alert(String msg) /*-{ 
      $wnd.alert(msg); 
     }-*/; 

    /**
     * This is the entry point method.
     */
    public void onModuleLoad() {

        alert("Hello World!"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot I figure the problem in the xml configuration . Just there were more than one EntryPoint defined in the gwt.xml file

Answer (score 0):

You're likely not running this code in DevMode, but in a plain JVM, where GWT cannot do its *magic*

Comment: No I am running it in the development mode :(